# RedisClient in StackExchange.Redis

Tags: stackexchange.redis

@MarcGravell.  I noticed that RedisClient (in ServiceStack.Redis) doesn't exists in StackExchange.Redis for Azure.  Any plan to make it available?
In particular, I'm using the RedisClient.AcquireLock for Distributed Lock.
Note: I was able to connect to Redis instance in Azure with ServiceStack.Redis as well, but it would be nice that will be available in StackExchange.Redis.

Comment: This should be an email, chat or whatever...

Comment: In instance, I believe that Marc has a perpetual subscription to [stackexchange.redis] tag, meaning that you don't need to call him with @ ;)

Comment: Also, @ doesn't work for notification purposes in post bodies :)

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack != StackExchange. They are entirely unrelated... However, SE.Redis does have methods for working with distributed locks - see the methods starting with the word `Lock` on `IDatabase` etc.

If there is some specific feature you are after: perhaps raise an issue on github. But: distributed / centralised locking is definitely provided. Specifically: Take, Release, Query and Extend.